# How do I query Prometheus for number of times a service is down

Tags: monitoring, grafana, prometheus

I am trying to work with the UP metric to determine the number of times the service was down for less than a minute (potentially a network hiccup) during a time range (or per hour). I am sampling at 5 seconds intervals

The best I got so far is up == 0 would give me a series with points only when the service was down but I am not sure what to do next.

Any help with this type of query would be greatly appreciated

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the following: calculate the average of the *up* metric. If the service goes down, the average (sliding windows of 1 minute) will decrease over time.

If the job comes up again, and the average is greater than 0, then the service wasn't down for more than one minute.

The following query (works via the Prometheus web console) delivers one data point for each time the service comes up before it was down for more than one minute.

```
avg_over_time(up{job="jobname"} [1m]) > 0 
AND 
irate(up{job="jobname"} [1m]) > 0
```

Comment: why the additional `AND irate(up{job="jobname"}[1m]) > 0`?